# Scheduled annotation and custom StringResolver

Tags: java, spring, spring-scheduled

I have several Spring `@Component`
each containing a `@Scheduled(cron="some cron expression")` method.

I need to initialize cron values on application startup from Database

So I created a custom Implementation of `StringValueResolver` that looks like this:

```
public class CustomEmbeddedValueResolver implements StringValueResolver {
@Override
public String resolveStringValue(String attribute1){
    // Search DataBase for key attribute1 and return String value of attribute1
    }
...
}
```

And Register it in

```
public class CustomScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor extends ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor {
    @Override
    public void setEmbeddedValueResolver(StringValueResolver resolver)
    {
    this.embeddedValueResolver = new CustomEmbeddedValueResolver(resolver, context);
    } 
...
}
```

My Components looks like

```
@Component
@EnableScheduling
public class MyScheduler {
    @Scheduled(cron = "Property1")
    public void method1()
    { }
}
```

So the problem is that CustomEmbeddedValueResolver  works fine. 
It looks database for "Property1" and returns String "0 1 * * * *"

But Scheduled methods did not run.

What is wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Don't... You are over complicating things. Instead of a custom a `CustomEmbeddedValueResolver` add a `PropertySource` that loads the properties from the database. That way everything else can remain the same.

Comment: Thank you very much. PropertySource works. 
But I have another issue now. 
In case I don't want to create Component with Scheduler at all (it is marked as disabled in database) I tried to use @ConditionalOnProperty("valueFromDatabaseLoadedByPropertySource"), but this Condition order is higher than PropertySource, and Component will never be created.

Comment: You should add the `PropertySource` very early using an `ApplicationContextInitializer` this would add it before any other component.